# is it possible to query a windows ldap server from a linux machine

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am attempting to query a Windows LDAP server from a CentOS 5.8 machine. Is this something that can be done?  Specifically, I attempt to query the LDAP server using 'ldapsearch'. Here is the query:

```
ldapsearch -V -h ldapserver.host.name -b 'YourADDN' -x -s base -z 1 -l 1 '(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))' @inetOrgPerson
```

Based on my results, I am not even sure if a connection from a Linux client to a Windows LDAP server is possible. If anyone can verify this, I'd be most appreciative. All I want to do is run the LDAP query `(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))`  from a Linux machine to the LDAP server and return results to the Linux server screen.

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's just TCP.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need proper permissions and not sure what the "@inetOrgPerson" is on the end. Try "*" for all attributes.

Comment: I would start by making sure that the host is reachable on the network, by ping-ing and traceroute-ing the ldap server from the Linux machine. Also it would help us that you actually provide any and all error messages you are experiencing.

Comment: Based on what results? If you have any results you've already proven that the commnunication is possible. If you're getting an error, or unexpected results, you need to provide them here, instead of positing implausible causes for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

```
ldapsearch -b "dc=example,dc=com" -D "xxx\user1" -x -W -h x.x.x.x -p 3268 "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=username))"
```

Answer (score -1):

**ldap search in unix**

```
\usr/bin/ldapsearch  -h <ipaddress>  -b 'DC=<domainname> , DC=com' -F'|' sAMAccountName=<name to search> extensionName personalPager url department physicalDeliveryOfficeName otherPager sAMAccountName name title mail manager mobile telephoneNumber  |  awk -F"|" '
{ if (NR!=1) {abc[NR]=$1"|"$2}} END { for (i in abc) {printf("%s\n",abc[i])}}' > ldap_out.txt
```